# Multiline Regex for 16 character string that has at least one uppercase AND one lowercase AND one digit

Tags: python, regex

How do I write a multiline regex for 16 character string that has at least one uppercase AND one lowercase AND one digit?

Comment: The same way as you write it for a single line, just use the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.